# Efficient Logic to get distinct values from a range of values in c# 2.0

Tags: c#

I have  a list of ranges. Each range has a from and to value, meaning the value can be between that range. For eample if range is (1,4)., the values can be 1,2,3 and 4. Now, I need to find the distinct values in a given list of range. Below is the sample code.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Range> values = new List<Range>();
        values.Add(new Range(1, 2));
        values.Add(new Range(1, 3));
        values.Add(new Range(1, 4));
        values.Add(new Range(3, 5));
        values.Add(new Range(7, 10));
        values.Add(new Range(7, 8));

        // Expected Output from the range of values
        //1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10
    }
}
class Range
{
    public Range(int _form, int _to)
    {
        from = _from;
        to = _to;
    }
    private int from;

    public int From
    {
        get { return from; }
        set { from = value; }
    }

    private int to;

    public int To
    {
        get { return to; }
        set { to = value; }
    }

}
```

I can loop through every range and find the distinct values. but if some one can give an effieient approach, it would be helpful.

Comment: what is the minimum and maximum value of `_from` and `_to`?

Comment: is this homework..? saw the same type of question yesterday posted online..

Comment: Not quite sure I understand what your asking here. Do you mean you want to find the distinct *ranges* or the value selected from the range?

Comment: the Minimum value is 1 and the maximun value is 1000

Comment: @james I need the distinct values, in the values select in the range.

Comment: @Muthukumar, if something is unclear in my answers - just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For a small number of intervals, the straightforward approach should do the trick.
- If most intervals fold into each other, you can perform a preliminary step of merging them to reduce the number of tests
- If the number of disjoint intervals is high, build an [*Interval Tree*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree). Here is a [link](http://www.thekevindolan.com/2010/02/interval-tree/index.html) to an article with code example in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider the following solution (I won't write full code, only general route):

- for each incoming Range adjust MinVal and MaxVal variables - to hold minimum value in all ranges, and maximum value in all ranges respectively
- build two collections of incoming Ranges, let one name be `Begins` and the other one `Ends`
- after all Ranges are collected sort both collections: `Begins` should be sorted according to `from` value and `Ends` should be sorted according to `to` value
- initialize `depth` counter variable to 0
- initialize `BeginPointer` and `EndPointer` to first element of respective collections
- now the crucial part: iterate from `MinVal` to `MaxVal`, if current value indicates beginning of collection (number at current `BeginPointer` is equal to iteration value) -> increase `depth` by 1 and move `BeginPointer` forward (repeat for consecutive "beginnings")
- if `depth` is greater then 0 -> print current iteration value as we are inside some range
- if current value indicates ending of collection -> decrease `depth` by 1 (repeat for consecutive "endings")

This will do for even big range of values. If maximum value is relatively low (i.e. 1000, as OP indicated in comments - consult my other answer).

Answer (score 1):

If range of `_from` and `_to` is small (1000 as indicated) you can use array[1000] of booleans. For each incoming Range set corresponding array elements to true. I.e. for Range(3,6), set array elements 3, 4, 5 and 6 to true. Now iterate over array and print every index that is true. Should be efficient enough for small ranges.